# Cardinality of infinite sequences of $0$ and $1$ $\geq |\mathbb{R}|$

Tags: cardinals, infinity

Think of all infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s. Let the set be $S$. I want to prove that the cardinality $|S|$ is greater than or equal to $|\mathbb{R}|$. I think it is useful to use the fact that the set $T$ of reals in $(0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. If I can create an injective function from $S$ to $T$ then it would imply $|S|=|T|=|\mathbb{R}|$. I think of taking the the infinite number in $S$, typically 10011001... and map to the number in $T$ with that decimal expansion, so 0.10011001.... Then wouldn't that be an injection?

Comment: Have you ever heard of numbers written in binary before?  Can you find a bijection between the set of real numbers in $[0,1]$ written in binary and your set $S$?

Comment: That is a indeed nice approach, I didn't think about binary numbers, so used to our decimal system...

Comment: Are we sure the decimal expansion is unique, for example 0.999...=1.0000...., but since we are in $(0,1)$ it is fine?

Comment: That is a good observation to make.  No, the decimal expansion is not technically unique, but you could instead show an injection from $[0,1)$ to $S$ by taking the binary expansion of the numbers where if given a choice between two representations, take the one with repeated zeroes instead of repeated ones.  This would at least show $|\Bbb R|\leq S$.  To show the other direction, then perhaps you can be a bit trickier, making those sequences which end in infinitely many repeated zeroes to the binary number in $[0,1)$ and with infinitely many repeated ones to numbers in $[1,2]$

Comment: @JMoravitz: If you want to inject $S$ into $\mathbb{R}$ just consider things like 0.11111110111... as decimal expansions rather than binary ones.

Comment: @user30523 0.99999... means the limit of sequence (0.9, 0.99, 0.999, ...). The limit (in this case 1) might not be in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

An injective map from S to $\mathbb{R}$ shows that $\mathbb{R}$ is bigger than S, not vice-versa.  But you're in the right ballpark for constructing the map.

Comment: Of course, it is the other way around. It does not matter for bijections but for injections the direction is crucial.